# JAVA: JAXB annotations inheritance from methods definition inside interfaces

Tags: java

I've no idea if annotations from methods definitions inside interfaces can be inherited by those methods implementations inside implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

They are not. Even with the `@Inherited` annotation:

From the `@Inherited` JavaDoc

```
...annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.
```

They however can be inherited in classes.